# Why aren't Java Class main methods implemented as final?

Tags: java

Java class's main method is implemented as:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // main method 
}
```

Why wasn't it implemented as `public static final void`? We can use the final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method cannot be overridden by subclasses, which seems like a desirable property for a class main method?

Perhaps it is because "[because a static method cannot be overridden](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-overload-and-override-main-method-in-java/)", and so the final keyword would be redundant, but I am curious if there are other reasons to be aware of.

Comment: What would `final` mean for a method, rather than a field? Java isn't Javascript, you don't just get to assign a new method signature and body to an existing class method name at runtime (you need to jump through _a lot_ of hoops if you want to break expectations that badly). As for preventing overrides in subclasses: why would that be necessary? Only the main method of the class that Java "starts the run on" gets invoked. You can have a million subclasses each with their own main and they would have zero effect?

Comment: What other reason is necessary than that `static` is essentially already `final`?

Comment: What would Java gain if it would require you to write the main method as a `public static final void` method? Note that although Java doesn't require that you write your main methods as `public static final void main(..)` you can still to write them that way if you desire.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've answered your own question. The `final` keyword prevents a method from being overridden. Since `static` methods cannot be overridden, it would be redundant to make the `main` method `final`.

Comment: It sounds like these keywords operate differently on variables, since `private static final` is commonly used to declare constants in Java?

Comment: Static variables can change their values. The `public static final` variation means, these values are like constants, `final` prevent changing them. This is different from declaring methods `final`.

Comment: The `final` keyword works differently on variables. The value of a `final` variable cannot be changed.